# What does an exponent on set notation mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm reading this [paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/file/8a20a8621978632d76c43dfd28b67767-Paper.pdf) that establishes SHAP values for Machine Learning explainability.

On page 2 of the paper they put some set builder notation to an exponent $M$, as below:

$$z' \in \{1, 0\}^M$$

I presume this means that $z'$ is a vector of size $M$, where each index takes the value $0$ or $1$.

Is this the correct way to interpret this notation?

Comment: Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Set_exponentiation) on set exponentiation

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Sorry, still struggling to understand after reading that resource, is my intuition right or not?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is valid

Comment: Excellent, and, to carry it forward, does that mean $\{1, 0\}^M$ represents every possible vector of $0$s or $1$s of length $M$?

Comment: Yes; in formal terms is the set of all functions from set $M$ to set $\{ 0,1 \}$. For simplicity, let $M = \{ a,b,c \}$: a function from $M$ to $\{ 0,1 \}$ is a function that maps $a$ to one of $0,1$ and $b$ to...

Comment: In those formal terms $M$ stands for $\{1,2,3,...,M\}$ in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since $M$ is a natural number ("the number of simplified input features"). In the paper, this is in the context of a definition
$$
g(z') = \phi_0 + \sum_{i=1}^M \phi_iz'_i
$$
where $z'$ is being indexed by $i$ for $1 \le i \le M$. The calculation is adding up $\phi_0$ and some of the other $\phi_i$ values, with $z'$ telling us which ones to include in the total.

More generally, people write $B^A$ for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$. If you like, you can think of $\{0,1\}^M$ as meaning the same as $\{0,1\}^{\{1, 2, \dots, M\}}$, which is the set of functions that take in a number between $1$ and $M$, and spit out either $0$ or $1$. If $f$ is a function like that, then you can make a vector of $0$s and $1$s:
$$
  (f(1), f(2), f(3), \dots, f(M)).
$$
And also, if you had a vector of that length, you could use it to define a function, just by indexing into the vector. So the function and the vector are really two different views of the same data. Mathematicians often switch freely between these viewpoints.